# What would cause lat/longs from Google Maps to be displayed offset in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, geocoding

any ideas [what's going on here](https://firestonerachel.cartodb.com/viz/5c00c1ea-7c02-11e5-b3ab-0ef24382571b/public_map)?

The lat/longs in this map have been manually picked up from Google Maps and loaded into the data table. I understand that CartDB and Google Maps both use WGS84 so this should "just work", right?

It looks like there's some kind of standard offset to the coordinates as they look roughly in the right positions relative to each other, but wrong absolute positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your latitude and longitudes appear to be reversed.

If you run the following in the SQL tray for that data table, it will reverse them:

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET the_geom = CDB_LatLng(ST_X(the_geom),ST_Y(the_geom))
```

It uses a built in CartoDB function (CDB_LatLng()), and two PostGIS functions: [`ST_X()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) and [`ST_Y()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html).

Be sure to change `your_table_name` to the actual name of your table. Also, this overwrites the geometrical data, so make sure you have a backup in case there are typos.

Comment: :) It happens to everyone. Luckily there are some easy tricks to undo it. There's also ST_FlipCoordinates: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_FlipCoordinates.html